# Superagent request is undefined

Tags: superagent

In version 3 of Superagent I was able to set a variable to the superagent request, like this:

```
const mySuperagent = superagent
  .get(getURL)
  .end(function (err, res) {})
```

And use `mySuperagent` elsewhere.

But I've updated Superagent to version 7.0.2 and now `mySuperagent` is 'undefined'.
Does anyone know what has changed because I can't figure it out?

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-pateu-7kr5gh?file=/src/api.ts

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: This is using Superagent v3.8.3:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-flower-m32nv9?file=/src/api.ts

You can see that lines 15 & 16 in api.ts log out the value for the variable `postRequest`


If you upgrade Superagent to v7.0.2 the same lines log out `undefined`